# \input in figure environment

Tags: graphics, floats, input, gnuplot, epslatex

I am trying to include an image that I created with gnuplot.
Therefore I used in gnuplot:

```
set terminal epslatex color
set output './bild.tex'
```

Now trying to include the image in my tex document:

```
\begin{figure}
    \input{bild.tex}
\end{figure}
```

Gives me the error:

"Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup. \end{figure}"

I have absolutely no idea what I might be doing wrong.

EDIT:
Example:

```
\documentclass[11pt,titlepage]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[british,UKenglish,USenglish,english,american]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \input{bild.tex}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Thanks for the help in advance!

Edit2:

Here is the code of bild.tex:

```
  % GNUPLOT: LaTeX picture with Postscript
\begingroup
  \makeatletter
  \providecommand\color[2][]{%
    \GenericError{(gnuplot) \space\space\space\@spaces}{%
      Package color not loaded in conjunction with
      terminal option `colourtext'%
    }{See the gnuplot documentation for explanation.%
    }{Either use 'blacktext' in gnuplot or load the package
      color.sty in LaTeX.}%
    \renewcommand\color[2][]{}%
  }%
  \providecommand\includegraphics[2][]{%
    \GenericError{(gnuplot) \space\space\space\@spaces}{%
      Package graphicx or graphics not loaded%
    }{See the gnuplot documentation for explanation.%
    }{The gnuplot epslatex terminal needs graphicx.sty or graphics.sty.}%
    \renewcommand\includegraphics[2][]{}%
  }%
  \providecommand\rotatebox[2]{#2}%
  \@ifundefined{ifGPcolor}{%
    \newif\ifGPcolor
    \GPcolortrue
  }{}%
  \@ifundefined{ifGPblacktext}{%
    \newif\ifGPblacktext
    \GPblacktexttrue
  }{}%
  % define a \g@addto@macro without @ in the name:
  \let\gplgaddtomacro\g@addto@macro
  % define empty templates for all commands taking text:
  \gdef\gplbacktext{}%
  \gdef\gplfronttext{}%
  \makeatother
  \ifGPblacktext
    % no textcolor at all
    \def\colorrgb#1{}%
    \def\colorgray#1{}%
  \else
    % gray or color?
    \ifGPcolor
      \def\colorrgb#1{\color[rgb]{#1}}%
      \def\colorgray#1{\color[gray]{#1}}%
      \expandafter\def\csname LTw\endcsname{\color{white}}%
      \expandafter\def\csname LTb\endcsname{\color{black}}%
      \expandafter\def\csname LTa\endcsname{\color{black}}%
      \expandafter\def\csname LT0\endcsname{\color[rgb]{1,0,0}}%
      \expandafter\def\csname LT1\endcsname{\color[rgb]{0,1,0}}%
      \expandafter\def\csname LT2\endcsname{\color[rgb]{0,0,1}}%
      \expandafter\def\csname LT3\endcsname{\color[rgb]{1,0,1}}%
      \expandafter\def\csname LT4\endcsname{\color[rgb]{0,1,1}}%
      \expandafter\def\csname LT5\endcsname{\color[rgb]{1,1,0}}%
      \expandafter\def\csname LT6\endcsname{\color[rgb]{0,0,0}}%
      \expandafter\def\csname LT7\endcsname{\color[rgb]{1,0.3,0}}%
      \expandafter\def\csname LT8\endcsname{\color[rgb]{0.5,0.5,0.5}}%
    \else
      % gray
      \def\colorrgb#1{\color{black}}%
      \def\colorgray#1{\color[gray]{#1}}%
      \expandafter\def\csname LTw\endcsname{\color{white}}%
      \expandafter\def\csname LTb\endcsname{\color{black}}%
      \expandafter\def\csname LTa\endcsname{\color{black}}%
      \expandafter\def\csname LT0\endcsname{\color{black}}%
      \expandafter\def\csname LT1\endcsname{\color{black}}%
      \expandafter\def\csname LT2\endcsname{\color{black}}%
      \expandafter\def\csname LT3\endcsname{\color{black}}%
      \expandafter\def\csname LT4\endcsname{\color{black}}%
      \expandafter\def\csname LT5\endcsname{\color{black}}%
      \expandafter\def\csname LT6\endcsname{\color{black}}%
      \expandafter\def\csname LT7\endcsname{\color{black}}%
      \expandafter\def\csname LT8\endcsname{\color{black}}%
    \fi
  \fi
    \setlength{\unitlength}{0.0500bp}%
    \ifx\gptboxheight\undefined%
      \newlength{\gptboxheight}%
      \newlength{\gptboxwidth}%
      \newsavebox{\gptboxtext}%
    \fi%
    \setlength{\fboxrule}{0.5pt}%
    \setlength{\fboxsep}{1pt}%
\begin{picture}(7200.00,5040.00)%
    \gplgaddtomacro\gplbacktext{%
      \csname LTb\endcsname%
      \put(946,704){\makebox(0,0)[r]{\strut{}$10.8$}}%
      \put(946,1286){\makebox(0,0)[r]{\strut{}$11$}}%
      \put(946,1867){\makebox(0,0)[r]{\strut{}$11.2$}}%
      \put(946,2449){\makebox(0,0)[r]{\strut{}$11.4$}}%
      \put(946,3030){\makebox(0,0)[r]{\strut{}$11.6$}}%
      \put(946,3612){\makebox(0,0)[r]{\strut{}$11.8$}}%
      \put(946,4193){\makebox(0,0)[r]{\strut{}$12$}}%
      \put(946,4775){\makebox(0,0)[r]{\strut{}$12.2$}}%
      \put(1078,484){\makebox(0,0){\strut{}$-0.8$}}%
      \put(2223,484){\makebox(0,0){\strut{}$-0.6$}}%
      \put(3368,484){\makebox(0,0){\strut{}$-0.4$}}%
      \put(4513,484){\makebox(0,0){\strut{}$-0.2$}}%
      \put(5658,484){\makebox(0,0){\strut{}$0$}}%
      \put(6803,484){\makebox(0,0){\strut{}$0.2$}}%
    }%
    \gplgaddtomacro\gplfronttext{%
      \csname LTb\endcsname%
      \put(176,2739){\rotatebox{-270}{\makebox(0,0){\strut{}Intensity [arb. unit]}}}%
      \put(3940,154){\makebox(0,0){\strut{}Time [s]}}%
      \put(3940,4665){\makebox(0,0){\strut{}}}%
    }%
    \gplbacktext
    \put(0,0){\includegraphics{./bild}}%
    \gplfronttext
  \end{picture}%
\endgroup
```

Comment: [Welcome to TEX.SE!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/82917) Please provide a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}` instead of code snippets. This makes our lives easier and increases the chance of people helping you.

Comment: At the very least you'll need to load the `graphicx` package. But the error has almost certainly to do with the plot itself, so you'll need to show _that_ code. As an educated guess I'd say something went wrong in defining labels or titles, but it's impossible to say anything without looking at the code.

Comment: I edited the code. I was able to close it by putting

    `set output`

at the end of the gnuplot script. However now the image is not loading. I assume that the .eps data type is not supported?

Comment: If I dont change `./bild`to `bild.eps`the image is not even being found.

Comment: You need to add `\usepackage{graphicx}` to your preamble in order to use the `.eps` image. But what exactly is `./bild`. **Is** it an EPS?

Answer (score 1):

The `.tex` file you show seems to be intended for inclusion with `\input`, as you tried.

When you try that, you are getting output on the console and in the log. This is telling you useful stuff e.g. that you need to load things in the preamble such as `color.sty`. (But better to load `\usepackage{xcolor}` instead.)

The first error I get is

```
! Package graphicx or graphics not loaded.
```

So, add

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
```

If you get an error about missing `color.sty`, also add

```
\usepackage{xcolor}
```

I don't get this, but I don't have `./bild`, so that is not so surprising. If this file is an EPS, adding the `.eps` extension to the file will enable `graphicx` to find it and convert it. If it isn't, adding this extension will obviously confuse things further.

```
\documentclass[11pt,titlepage]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[british,american]{babel}% US is default; UK is a second available language
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}% remove demo - you have bild, but I don't!
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \input{bild}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Because I had to use `demo` mode, it isn't very impressive:

[image: unimpressive demo]